# PHP Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method UserEntity::setIdUser()

Tags: php, crud

I'm trying to make my READ statement in my CRUD in PHP but I do not see where is the problem.
The full mmessage error is the following:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method UserEntity::setIdUser() in C:\xampp\htdocs\WEBSERVICES\backend\model\dataLayer.class.php:111 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\WEBSERVICES\backend\index.php(8): DataLayer->getUsers() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\WEBSERVICES\backend\model\dataLayer.class.php on line 111

**And here is my code:**

```
function getUsers(){
$sql= 'SELECT * FROM `jstore_ecommerce`.`customers` '; 
try{
    $result = $this -> connexion -> prepare($sql); 
    $var = $result -> execute(); 
    $users = []; 

    while ($data = $result -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
        $user = new UserEntity();  
        $user -> setIdUser($data->id);               **//This is the line 111 in dataLayer**
        $user -> setEmail($data -> email); 
        $user -> setSexe($data ->sexe); 
        $user -> setFirstname($data -> firstname); 
        $user -> setLastname($data -> lastname); 
        $users[] = $user; 
    }

    if($users) {
        return $users;
    }
    else{
        return FALSE; 
    }
}
catch(PDOException $th){
    return NULL;    

}
```

}

**They are also refering to my index:**

```
    require 'config/config.php'; 
require 'entity/userEntity.php';    
require 'model/dataLayer.class.php'; 

$db= new DataLayer(); 

$users = $db -> getUsers();    **// This is the line 8 in index.php**
var_dump($users);
```

**And userEntity regarding user is this:**

```
class UserEntity{
    protected $idUser; 
    protected string $email; 
    protected ?int $sexe; 
    protected ?string $firstname;
    protected ?string $lastname;
}

function getIdUser() { 
    return $this->idUser; 
} 

function setIdUser($idUser) {  
    $this->idUser = $idUser; 
}
```

Can someone know where is the problem, why they do not reconize my method ?
UserEntity::setIdUser()

Greetings,

Comment: shouldn't the methods of the class be defined inside the class?

Comment: Your functions must be in your class body

Comment: That is it ! so simple I was looking elsewhere thanks mates

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).